# DRYly and consisely write a recursive function

Tags: python, recursion, dry

I'm writing a recursive function that looks something like this:

```
def mah_recursive_function(some_arg, some_option=True):
    if some_thing:
        some_arg.doFancyStuff();
        mah_recursive_function(some_arg,
                               some_option=some_option
        )
    elif some_thing:
        some_arg.doOtherFancyStuff();
        mah_recursive_function(some_arg,
                               some_option=some_option
        )
```

Obviously, those `some_option=some_option` assignments are really redundant, and, since I have more than one permanent kwarg option, the redundant assignments are getting really annoying.

```
from functools.magical_stuff import get_current_kwargs
mah_recursive_function(
    some_arg, **get_current_kwargs()
)
```

I would rather not bloat my recursive calls with redundant lines.  What is the best way to go about this?

Comment: Could you cut that down to a minimal example? It will be easier to answer and more useful for future users I think.

Comment: I won't have time to write up an answer, but ActiveState [has a recipe for it](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/491265-automatic-recursion/). I think they key is that you will need to make copies of your args/kwargs in each recursive call or else you will be modifying args/kwargs for all calls every time you modify them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using a wrapper function to avoid repetition:

```
def recursive_func_wrapper(arg, option=True):
    def recursive_func(arg):
        if option: recursive_func(new_arg)
        else: recursive_func(new_arg2)
    return recursive_func(arg)
```

Your option is automatically propagated (as a local variable) to the inner function, which can recurse as usual without any repetition of the `option=` argument.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a minimal example of what I think you want to accomplish with recursion - generally use the same values every time but have the flexibility to change a few of them. Does this do what you want?

The key point is to get copies of your args/kwargs or else you will be modifying the args/kwargs for every incomplete call any time you change something.

You could dress it up more with a decorator that automatically provides both the originals and the copies, perhaps even without having to break out the current names.

```
def factorial(*args_this_call, **kwargs_this_call):
    print('-----------------------------'
          '\nargs: {}'
          '\nkwargs: {}'.format(args_this_call, kwargs_this_call))
    # get copies so you don't modify the values of other calls that are waiting to complete
    args_next_call = list(args_this_call)
    kwargs_next_call = kwargs_this_call.copy()

    # you can break out the content of args / kwargs for clarity if you are going to use them a lot
    arg1, arg2 = args_this_call  # not used - just for example
    n = kwargs_this_call['n']

    # do your work
    if n == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        # modify whichever args/kwargs you want, leave the ones you don't want to change
        args_next_call[1] += 1  # some random modification
        kwargs_next_call['call_id'] += 1
        kwargs_next_call['n'] -= 1  # n-1 for factorial in this case

        # make the call
        result = n * factorial(*args_next_call, **kwargs_next_call)
        return result

# test the factorial with args/kwargs
args = (1, 1)  # just some values
kwargs = {'call_id': 1,
          'n': 4}
print(factorial(*args, **kwargs))
```

Result:

```
-----------------------------
args: (1, 1)
kwargs: {'call_id': 1, 'n': 4}
-----------------------------
args: (1, 2)
kwargs: {'call_id': 2, 'n': 3}
-----------------------------
args: (1, 3)
kwargs: {'call_id': 3, 'n': 2}
-----------------------------
args: (1, 4)
kwargs: {'call_id': 4, 'n': 1}
24
```